# How to add margin to a ScrollView scrollbar?

Tags: android, xml

Here is my `ScrollView` with its scrollbar below:

[image]

Here's the `style`:

```
<style name="ScrollBarStyle">
    <item name="android:height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">insideInset</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scrollbar</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">2000</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade">1000</item>
</style>
```

xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/profileScroll"
    style="@style/ScrollBarStyle"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_profile"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.75"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
```

drawable/scrollbar.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="1dp"/>
            <size android:height="100dp" android:width="15dp"/> // this size attribute doesn't change the size of the scrollbar
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

How can I add a margin between the scrollbar and `ScrollView`? So it's not on the far side but abit more central. As you can see in my `style` I've tried margin and padding but they arn't working.

I would also like to reduce the height of the scrollbar so it's only half the size of its enclosing `ScrollView`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It works in my case:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: That's not working? Your scrollbar is maximum height (I want it only half of its parent view) and there is also no margin on the right side (there should be blue space to the right of the scrollbar)

Comment: Don't understand what you exactly want to be honest. Can you explain with more details please ?

Comment: On the image right bottom corner is that the scrollview indicator ?

Comment: The `ScrollView` is the whole image - the image right bottom corner is the scrollbar, which scrolls the content of the `ScrollView`. I Photoshopped it in that image - that's what I want it to be in my app.